# Build Query string for function to query LDAP via SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory, ldap

```
INPUT_STRING NVARCHAR(MAX)
RETURNS NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS 
BEGIN

DECLARE @NewString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SelectClause NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @INPUT_STRING = @NewString

SET @SelectClause = 'SELECT *  FROM OpenQuery (' + ' 
  ADSI, ' + '
  ''SELECT  samaccountname
  FROM ''LDAP://' +  @NewString  +
  ')'' + '' AS tblADSI'''

 EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @SelectClause
```

Input string is something like this

```
CN=firstName\, Lastname,OU=MyOU,OU=AnotherOU,OU=Accounts,DC=enterprisenet,DC=org
```

Error message is as reads.

> Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 8
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')' + ' AS tblADSI'
>    EXEC sp_EXECUTESQL @SelectClause

Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Why aren't you issuing this query against your Active Directory instance directly?

Comment: Print out your @SelectClause so you can see where your single quotes are boogered up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this....

```
declare @INPUT_STRING nvarchar(MAX); 
SET @INPUT_STRING = 'CN=firstName\, Lastname,OU=MyOU,OU=AnotherOU,OU=Accounts,DC=enterprisenet,DC=org';

DECLARE @NewString NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SelectClause NVARCHAR(MAX)
SET @NewString = @INPUT_STRING 

SET @SelectClause = N'SELECT *  FROM OpenQuery (ADSI,'
                 +  N'  ''SELECT  samaccountname '
                 +  N'  FROM ''''LDAP://' +  @NewString  + N''''' '') AS tblADSI'
```

### Check

```
PRINT @SelectClause


SELECT *  
FROM OpenQuery (ADSI,  
               'SELECT  samaccountname   
                FROM ''LDAP://CN=firstName\, Lastname,OU=MyOU,OU=AnotherOU,OU=Accounts,DC=enterprisenet,DC=org'' 
               ') AS tblADSI
```